# PSQLException: ERROR: relation doesn't exist

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm using Hibernate and PostgreSQL database. **I have several schemas (and many tables in each of them)** and a generic method which takes an entity class and returns all entries depending on passed entity:

`public <T> List<T> getAll(Class<T> entityClass)`

After finding the table name of entity ("EMPLOYEE" for example),  it does    `List list = criteria.list();`  which creates this sql `SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE`. But it throws `PSQLException: ERROR: relation doesn't exist` because it must be `SELECT * FROM MYSCHEMA.EMPLOYEE` (schema must be appended). How to handle it?

This is not my method, as i'm using Spring Data JPA in persistence layer and it has no problem with identifying a schema and i'm not good in native hibernate. I'm trying to help my colleague.

And here's the method:

```
 @Override
@Transactional
public <T> List<T> getAll(Class<T> entityClass, Map<String, Object> filter, String... fetchProfiles) {
    Session session;
    try {
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        if (fetchProfiles != null) {
            for (String fetchProfile : fetchProfiles) {
                session.enableFetchProfile(fetchProfile);
            }
        }
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(entityClass);

        if (filter != null) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : filter.entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getValue() == null) {
                    criteria.add(Restrictions.isNull(entry.getKey()));
                } else {
                    if (entry.getValue() instanceof Collection) {
                        criteria.add(Restrictions.in(entry.getKey(), (Collection) entry.getValue()));
                    } else if (entry.getValue() instanceof BetweenValue) {
                        BetweenValue bv = (BetweenValue) entry.getValue();
                        if (bv.getBoundLeft() != null) {
                            criteria.add(Restrictions.ge(entry.getKey(), bv.getBoundLeft()));
                        }
                        if (bv.getBoundRight() != null) {
                            criteria.add(Restrictions.le(entry.getKey(), bv.getBoundRight()));
                        }
                    } else if (BaseEntity.class.isAssignableFrom(ReflectionUtils.findField(entityClass, entry.getKey()).getType()) && entry.getValue() instanceof Long) {
                        BaseEntity fieldEntity = null;
                        try {
                            fieldEntity = (BaseEntity) ReflectUtils.createFieldInstance(entityClass, entry.getKey());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        fieldEntity.setId((Long) entry.getValue());
                        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(entry.getKey(), fieldEntity));
                    } else {
                        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
        List list = criteria.list();
        if (fetchProfiles != null) {
            for (String fetchProfile : fetchProfiles) {
                session.disableFetchProfile(fetchProfile);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: @Billy Frost  check to edit

Comment: @Billy Frost Is there a way to tell Criteria which schema to look for?

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting (check your postgres log file, it should tell you the name of the relation that doesn't exist) and what's the actual name of the table (check psql/pgadmin). My guess is there's a case sensitivity issue.

Comment: @eurotrash The error is: PSQLException: ERROR: relation doesn't exist. Because `session.createCriteria(entityClass)` doesn't append schema name while creating SQL query. So `SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE` throws the error above. Sql query must be as such: `SELECT * FROM MYSCHEMA.EMPLOYEE`

Answer (score 2):

For Postgres you might get this if your table name is not lower case